# When using NSSearchField , secondary NSTableView looses focus and do not update simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I am using core data binding in cocoa app. My app has three NSTableViews bound to there NSArrayControllers in relationship such that if first table is selected, relevant data using Core data relationship is shown in the other two tables.

I have hooked NSSearchField to first NSArrayController. The problem is when search begins the other two tables do not remain in sync with the first one.They show nothing at all.

The other two tables only shows content when first one if clicked by user. 
How can I make all three NSTables update simultaneously when search occurs.

Comment: Try the "continuously updates value" option everywhere.

Comment: @stevesliva, still not updating even after  "continuously updates value" selected for all NSTable.

Comment: The key one would be the search field...  but I'm not sure it's really a solution, just something to try, hence just a comment.  Good luck. +1.

Comment: Switch on 'Avoid Empty Selection' of the array controller of the first table view.

Comment: @Willeke, 'Avoid Empty Selection' is turned on by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have this solution which works, I would like to know if this can be improved further.

Since when search starts the first NSTableView's selection is lost and hence the connected tables too, although the table is updated correctly showing filtered value. I am setting self as observer for change is NSArrayController selectedObject.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
[super awakeFromNib];
[_firstArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedObjects" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
}
```

Now I am observing for changes and if selected object do change and if NSSearchField is the one changing it, programatically select NSTableView first row

```
    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)
object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSResponder *firstResponder = [[NSApp keyWindow] firstResponder];
if ([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSText class]] && [(id)firstResponder delegate] == _searchField) {
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
    [_authorTable selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
}
}
```

Since when filtering using NSSearchField, the first object is what the most relevant, hence I am setting selection to row 0.